# Can I set up sharepoint 2013 on Windows Surface Pro 2

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, sharepoint-foundation, environment

Can I set up sharepoint 2013 on Windows Surface Pro 2 ? I am going to buy surface pro 2 and would like to know whether it is possible or not. Thanks in advance.

Simply for us there was a dispute. Whether it is possible to set up SharePoint 2013 on Surface Pro 2. I think that it possible to make. Thus HiperV needs to be established, on it establish Windows Server 2012 + SharePoint 2013. Dispute is considered solved if on the virtual machine we can start Central Administration page. About further stable work the speech doesn't go. Will be used the cheapest version with 64 gigabytes of memory.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to install SharePoint on a surface?

Comment: yes, sharepoint 2013

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It is certainly not possible on the RT. Probably possible on the PRO, but then I would use a virtual machine on it for running SP

Comment: The point is, that I don't want to use RT I am going to use Pro.

Comment: Still, why run SharePoint directly on it? SharePoint 2013 needs about 20GB of RAM with all services..

Comment: Sure I may run virtual machine. I am trying to understand is it possible at all.

Comment: It isn't, you do not have enough RAM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surface PRO has not sufficient hardware capacity to let your SharePoint 2013 runs

**Hardware requirements—web servers, application servers, and single server installations**
[image]

**Hardware requirements—database servers**

[image]

**Minimum software requirements**

- Minimum requirements for a database server in a farm:
- One of the following:
- The 64-bit edition of Microsoft SQL Server 2012.
- The 64-bit edition of SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1
- The 64-bit edition of Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (SP1) Standard, Enterprise, or Datacenter or the 64-bit edition of Windows Server 2012 Standard or Datacenter
- The SharePoint parsing process crashes in Windows Server 2008 R2 (KB 2554876)
  FIX: IIS 7.5 configurations are not updated when you use the ServerManager class to commit configuration changes (KB 2708075)
- Hotfix: ASP.NET (SharePoint) race condition in .NET 4.5 RTM:
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 (KB 2759112)
- Windows Server 2012 (KB 2765317)
- Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.5

ref: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(v=office.15).aspx#reqOtherCap

Comment: I am going to check this)

Comment: I concur with Salvatore. While it might be possible to get it installed as a dev environment, even if it can be installed the performance is likely to be so poor as to be unusable. If you still want to try it, go for it, but just be prepared for the worst.

Comment: Also we are talking to install SP on board not using VM. On my current laptop I have 32gb and I gave 16gb to SP where Microsoft suggestions are to assign no less of 20Gb!!!!